# Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' to database 'depot_test'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am a bit stumped here. I have created a database and have had no issues using the depot_production database. However, of late whenever I run rake test, I get a bunch of errors like

```
# Running tests:

EEEEEEEE

Finished tests in 0.031499s, 253.9763 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1) Error:
test_should_create_product(ProductsControllerTest):
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' to database 'depot_test'
```

The odd thing is I think my database.yml file is fine. And everytime I run db:migrate I just get an empty line returned to me. I also added a user test, but I think that only added it to my development database. I sorta think my test and production and databases don't exist...

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: depot_development
pool: 5
username: root
password: admin
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: depot_test
pool: 5
username: test
password: testy
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: depot_production
pool: 5
username: prod
password: mypassword
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Thanks for sticking with me here. I feel like I am close but something is odd. Here is what I did.

```
 mysql> use depot_test;
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'depot_test'
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| depot_development  |
| development        |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> use depot_test
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'depot_test'
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON `test` TO test@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testy';
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.test' doesn't exist
mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON `depot_test` TO test@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY       'testy';
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.depot_test' doesn't exist
```

Comment: you need to grant permissions to the user "test" to alter "depot_test"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So first login as **root** or whatever your root user is called from terminal.

```
mysql -u root -p

CREATE DATABASE depot_test

CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass123';

USE depot_test
```

Once you are logged in to mysql, grant privileges to the user `test` (remember to change password)

```
GRANT ALL privileges on depot_test.* to test@localhost identified by 'mypass123';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You will need to change your pass to "mypass123" in your database.yml

Comment: Thanks! I tried and got the following. ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Comment: oh yea you have to select the `depot_test` database, see the edit

Comment: Sorry, message was too long. I have edited my original post and added it. Thanks!

Comment: It seems you have no database called `depot_test` but you have one called `test` so we will create `depot_test`

Comment: RAILS_ENV=depot_test rake db:create
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
My database.yml file looks fine to me. I am adding it to the original post as well.

Comment: yep its not on the rails side, i had some problems with my code, logout and try everything from top down.

Comment: I owe you a beer or something, sorry for all the hassle man. I am close though. I have the database made and the username created. Only thing that doesn't work is changing that user's privileges. I get mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON DATABASE `depot_test` TO test@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testy';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATABASE `depot_test` TO test@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testy'' at line 1

Comment: no worries, lemme actually try running that command. Oh dont forget to rate, id appreciate it :)

Comment: k logout and start from the `USE` command, no need to create user/db again.

Comment: Worked like a charm! And I rated the post. Thanks so much.

Comment: Good to hear! Rails is always a pain to install, your lucky you only had mysql issues :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by **@1337holiday** will work, but I guess in most cases we do not want to `GRANT ALL` permissions to the database which we  want to allow someone to connect to. If you are like me and, for example, just want to give **read only access** to the particular database, then you can simply grant a specific privilege to the database or to its objects (`GRANT SELECT` for example) - and assigning this permission [will grant a connect privilege to the particular mysql schema/database as well](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html). I guess it is not that clear from documentation, but having any granted privilege on this database or its objects (SELECT, CREATE, DELETE, UPDATE, DROP and [many others](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#:%7E:text=Table%C2%A013.11%C2%A0Permissible%20Static%20Privileges%20for%20GRANT%20and%20REVOKE)) will be sufficient enough to just connect to the database.

So you can issue statements like this (by the root or user, who has enough privileges)

```
CREATE USER 'local' IDENTIFIED WITH 'caching_sha2_password' BY 'local';
CREATE DATABASE local;
GRANT SELECT ON local.* TO 'local';
```

and thereafter `local` user will have the ability to connect to `local` database, using:

```
USE local;
```

or by the means of the programming language client. I hope it was helpful :)