# Rails Console, Password needed to create new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently trying to complete a tutorial on ruby on rails and have had this error within IRB when I enter "subject = Subject.new"

```
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'simple_cms'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

is there a way to supply this to irb when i run

```
rails console
```

What is the best way to resolve this?

database.yml is below:

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
host: localhost
pool: 5
username: simple_cms
password: mypasshere
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_development

  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_production
  username: simple_cms
  password: <%= ENV['SIMPLE_CMS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Much appreciated for any help!

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003338/mysql2error-access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-to-database-depot-test

Comment: This sounds like the credentials in database.yml aren't correct