# Mysql2::Error Access denied for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some rails applications on my mac and they work just fine. 
I have just installed a new one that uses mysql2 gem, I am starting
the server but when I am visiting the application I am getting an 
Access denied error.
I am trying to follow this solution 
    [Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' to database 'depot_test'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003338/mysql2error-access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-to-database-depot-test)
I am logging in as a root user but when I am trying to create a new database I am getting an access denied error.

Comment: Did you setup the `config/database.yml` file? Rails will not run MySQL as the shell user but rather as the user you specify in your `/database.yml`.

Comment: yes I have a database.yml file.

Comment: user test exists? and the password is correct?

Comment: change in your  config/database.yml user test to root. test user does not exist in your mysql

Answer (score 1):

Changes in your `config / database.yml` the user name root. test user does not exist in MySQL. I think in your development environment should look like:

Example

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: depot_test
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  encoding: utf8
  username: test
  password:
```

Change `username` to `root` or create test user with privileges. Remember that Rails uses environments(test, development, production u other). In your case is `depot_development` or another name that is not equal to another environment.

I hope it helps you.