# rails is not using the configuration set on database.yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: testing
  pool: 5
  username: ubuntu
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

When I run `rake db:setup` I got this:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "database"=>"testing", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"ubuntu", "host"=>"127.0.0.1"}
-- create_table("documents", {:force=>:cascade})
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'testing'
```

Why it's not using my username and host? instead is showing `'' @ 'localhost'`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost. Did you hide the password or there is no password at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think, database.yml config for production environment, but you run it on development environment. You can use 'RAILS_ENV=development rake db:setup' or 'RAILS_ENV=test rake db:setup'
One more thing, database should be created by mysql user with root privileges

Comment: No I'm running like `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create` if you see the log its taking the right params

Comment: You issue seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003338/mysql2error-access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-to-database-depot-test

Comment: No it's not that, my issue is that rails is not using the params i set on database.yml even when it shows it on the log.

Comment: No, params here at anything. MySQL say error because 'ubuntu' user don't have permission for creating db. Did you created 'ubuntu' user from mysql console?

Comment: Maybe you should write 'password' after 'username'?

Comment: you was right, seems like a mysql thing, I connected to mysql using the user `ubuntu`, and when I run `create database testing` it gives an error with an empty username

Comment: Can you check the mysql logs to check if the username is actually being passed to mysql?